# What features will make this creature OP?

Tags: aliens, fauna

I'm designing several alien worlds, I want each to be very unique.  One idea I had (thanks to an online [alien fauna generator](https://www.scifiideas.com/alien-species-generator/)) was a planet where one species has wiped out all other creatures.  It could be called an Osajuc.  (Thanks again to [AFG](https://www.scifiideas.com/alien-species-generator/).)  I like this idea, as it would indeed be a very unique environment.

However, having one species dominate an ecosystem so completely sounds... implausible.  I have some ideas about how it could be less implausible but want some suggestions and guidance from you about this problem, particularly about the traits and features of this Osajuc.

One important detail is that there is no sentient life on this planet.  The Osajuc might be a very intelligent animal, but it cannot be human or near-human in its intelligence.

##### Some info about the planet:

---

> "The planet is incredibly inhospitable.  I think we should be more surprised that there are *any* large creatures, than that there seems to be only one."

I want this planet to be very harsh, to emphasise the obliteration of other animal life by the Osajuc.  It will have a long year and long days, and a large axial tilt.  Because of these, it will have a very cold and dark winter.

The surface of the planet is rocky, with minimal foliage.  Similar to the scoria fields on Rangitoto (see image at end).  I do not want it to have large open oceans, but it may have a lot of water sitting between the piled rocks that make up its surface.

(If you think a water world would be easier for an animal species to have domination of, say so, and why.  I am still open to adjusting many things about this world.)

#### Other life

---

> "Well, it's not quite the *only* life on the planet:  we found a nest of ant-like insects, and there are a variety of small plants and fungi.  But there is only one species of large animal."

Clearly, it is either impossible or incredibly unlikely for a planet to host only a single species.  Because of that, I have decided that this is just the only large animal.  There are small trees, but no more than 3m in height (at the absolute tallest).  The ground is mostly rocky, but there are small plants growing in and around the crevices.

There are insects, but vastly fewer than on Earth.  There might be small vertebrates, but no larger than a small mouse.  I expect that all "other creatures" will spend a lot of time underground.

---

Given this background (and advice from comments), I have come up with some ideas for what this Osajuc has as its features.

#### Working concept of an Osajuc:

It moves in packs, has intelligence similar to a dolphin, and has a good memory; it is able to learn from the actions of its kin.
It breeds rapaciously, swarming over the surface of the planet like locusts in summertime, devouring all plant (and other animal) life it comes across, leaving a barren rocky wasteland in its wake.
In wintertime, the strongest individuals survive by cannibalism.  These become the leaders of the next year's herds.

Maybe it hibernates?  But this seems like it would allow space for creatures that can withstand the winter to thrive.
Maybe it has chlorophyll or retinase in its blood, to provide more energy for growth, but this might be useless during the wintertime.

---

## Question

Given the above, what do you think would be necessary for the Osajuc to dominate its home planet?  Is my working concept at least semi-plausible?  What would you do to improve it?

---

#### Appendix:

This would represent a well-vegetated area of the planet:
[image: Rangitoto lava field]

Comment: I know things like this are fun, but please remember some policies/rules that might get in the way of this question. (a) Mindless social fun is prohibited ([help/dont-ask]) as is [purposeless] brainstorming ([help/on-topic]). We don't answer questions about 3rd-party or commercial worlds and since this isn't a creature of your own design, it might fall into that. Worse, a creature that could drive "every other species" (insects? bacteria? plants?) extinct would also be extinct. Finally, since humans haven't achieved this goal, it's hard to imagine non-sapient features that could.

Comment: *"They have driven every other species on their planet to extinction":* No they didn't, or else they have driven themselves to extinction too. Mammals must eat *something*.

Comment: If their ear holes are small enough then no one could give them a wet willy. I don't have to tell you what comes next. The extinction of all other species is the least of the possible consequences.

Comment: The book, The Legacy of Heorot; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legacy_of_Heorot is a guide to just such an ecosystem.

Comment: @Infinite_Maelstrom    Why do you interpret "every other species" as  "every other (non-animal, non-microscopic) species"?

Comment: @JBH --- I concur with you except on the third party bit. I see where you're coming from, that the given description belongs to AFG, but the OP specifies that she's using AFG for inspirational purposes. We get loads of questions with such qualifiers as "kind  of like in Marvel or Tolkien etc". So long as the OP fleshes out that description, I at least would not VTC for that particular reason. **However,** as written, this is pretty clearly brainstorming!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the query is an open ended brainstorming session. Cool, but not fit for this forum.

Comment: @elemtilas I get your point, but I found it hard to believe the OP was "inspired" when what we're being asked to rationalize is directly quoted from the description provided by the 3rd party generator. While certainly my weakest argument, I feel the example stands unsteadily upon the line.

Comment: Sorry for going AWOL for a few days, seems like my question was not as well-received as I'd hoped.  I'll edit it a bit based on the feedback, and see what people think.
@M.A.Golding: I interpreted it that way because it seemed entirely impractical to assume otherwise.

Comment: @JBH I'm trying to create a large number of wildly different ecosystems for various planets.  I was using this generator app to give starting points and a few ideas to help with this.  Perhaps I should not have quoted the entirety of its text, but I thought that would be helpful (quoting things is usually a Good Thing in my background in science and engineering).  I will edit the question to remove the direct quote, and give further clarity on my ideas about this creature's planet.

Comment: @Gillgamesh  That book does have a very good parallel to this planet, though I do not plan to set an entire story here.

Comment: @Infinite_Maelstrom While that would have avoided my 3rd-party/commercial world concern, it wouldn't have avoided my other concern at all. The overly simplistic generator included a conclusion that's impossible in nature and impossible to rationalize. I'm surprised they included it. It doesn't even make sense. Worse, by asking how a single-sentence "evolutionary consequence" can come to pass, you violate the [help/dont-ask]'s book rule (too broad). This wasn't a good question for this site. it's too speculative and too opinion-based. Questions are required to be specific and well scoped.

Comment: Alright, I have written a thoroughly reworked question.  Hopefully, this new version meets the criteria for a good question and can be re-opened.

Comment: What level of realism are you looking for here?  Single-environment life-supporting planets are effectively impossible given that temperature differences between the poles and equator are typically 50 C or more, so are you looking at a single habitable land mass over a small latitude range and the oceans are out of scope?  If vegetation is so sparse and there are no competing species, why are they pack/herd animals at all?  How is significant intelligence of benefit?  The question is much improved, but still seems to be a brainstorming exercise.

Comment: Edits cannot invalidate existing answers. Therefore edit rolled back.

Comment: @JBH  Perceived impossibility should never be a reason to VtC. The perception of impossibility only means you have not figured out a solution yourself.  It does not actually mean it is impossible, and VtCing it only serves to stop people who can figure it out from answering.

Comment: @Nosajimiki (a) I didn't vote to close this question. (b) without the OP's clarification, your rebuttal is irrational (even on this site). (c) The reason close/open voting requires multiple votes is that I'm not obligated to your opinion any more than you're obligated to mine. (d) At your convenience, please explain how it's possible for a species to survive after having driven all other species on the planet extinct. Every animal, plant, insect, amoeba, bacteria... everything. You're not allowed to make assumptions - you can only take the phrase as written. Cheers. I'm listening.

Comment: @JBH One solution would be a primary producer who's metabolic process makes the environment inhospitable to other life.  For example, imagine a thermophile that develops a new primary producer mechanism that creates sulphur hexafluoride as a biproduct.  It could turn an Earth like world into a Venus like world, killing all other life except other thermophiles... who may find the Sulphur hexafluoride inherently toxic.

Comment: @JBH oh, and I did not mean to invalidate any other reasons why this question should be closed, just that "a conclusion that's impossible in nature and impossible to rationalize." is not unto itself a reason to VtC because it in no way predicts how opinion based or broad the answers will be.  I often come across questions that seem stupidly impossible to me, assume everyone will give various wild "magic" solutions, and then someone comes along with a good idea, and then I'm like "Oh yeah, that's totally rational if you solve it that way".

Comment: But if I VtC just because **I** can't answer it, then the OP misses out on that answer.  If you come across a question that is allowed on the site, but can not be answered as asked, then you should contest that fact as a Frame Challenge, not a VtC.

Comment: @Nosajimiki You can actually imagine a world that would have but one evolutionary end game? We only have one data point to work with: Earth. And that datapoint suggests it would be impossible for a planet to evolve such a narrow sliver of life. In other words, I don't believe you've posited a valid answer and therefore find myself rejecting the idea that "just because I can't answer it" was the reason I voted to close. Wait... I didn't vote to close. I merely pointed out that the proposed question was impossible - even for suspension of disbelief.

Comment: @JBH, There are plenty of data points to pull from, but comments are not for detailed answers.  More importantly, you are missing the point that closing is the wrong response to an impossible question.  "That is impossible" is a valid  Frame Challenge if you can back it up with facts.  If you close a well asked question because the premise seems impossible, then similar questions just get asked again and again because it can't be researched.

Comment: There is also the idea on WB.SE of the "best possible answer".  If one person has an answer that would kill all fauna, and another person has an answer that would kill all flora and fauna, then the second answer is still more right than the 1st; so, it could still be the accepted answer even if its not a perfect answer.

Answer (score 3):

The answer I'm going to give is the following:

What makes Humans OP? Afterall - we've managed to wipe out a good number of species directly and indirectly.

1: The ability to understand complex Ideas.

I don't know the level of intelligence of a Dolphin specifically, but whilst they are pretty smart - I don't know how far they go with complexity. That said, some behaviors of Dolphins and specifically Killer Whales (Orcas - yes they are part of the Dolphin family ;) ) definitely suggests some order of understanding complexity.

2: The ability to communicate complex ideas.

So, we have our one genius, which is all well and good - but if that Genius member of the species can't get their ideas to others in the group, then it's all gone when that member dies. The ability to communicate is as foundational as being able to understand - because once you can understand and communicate...

3: Team Tactics vs 1v1 me bro.

All the best Apex predators (Wolves, Humans, Dolphins, Orcas, Lions etc.) hunt co-operatively. This is such a massive advantage that it really needs to be stressed. Life isn't like the Movies - even in humans getting jumped by more than 1 attacker is a such a huge disadvantage - you can (generally) only focus on one person at a time whereas they can both focus on you. One can work on distraction/interruption (holding your arms, getting behind you etc.) whilst the other works on Offence. Teamwork really is OP.

4: Teaching/Education/Parenting.

Back to our Orcas again - They teach 'Special techniques' for hunting - we know this because different distinct pods of Orcas in different areas have specific hunting skills - whether it's deliberate beaching to get Seals, using their tail flukes to send water pulses into schools of fish, biting off the barbs from Stingrays or flooding icebergs with a team - these tactics are consciously taught by the mature animals/parents to their young. Humans took this one step further with reading and writing - but the essential element is the same - taking knowledge and passing it to the next generation is Really OP.

5: And finally the Most OP thing of all (and perhaps where your creatures might not be as OP as written...) **Being able to hold nature at bay**

All the things I mentioned - other Animals to a greater or lesser degree can do. Communication, Teamwork, teaching etc. However - It's our expanded Tool use and our ability to craft things to help us survive that puts us Humans in a league of our own. Nature is hard, nature is brutal. Lost your Canines in a Fight? You are probably going to suffer a long and slow starvation. However if you can fashion a tool or weapon and retain hunting effectiveness, then you can sustain yourself for much longer than would normally be possible. Being able to build a tool to target a species or animal that you naturally would not be able to - again, massive advantage **and one that allows a species to sustain itself after it's wiped out another species**

So that's what would make a species OP: Intelligence, Communication, Teamwork, Teaching and tool use/building things.

Comment: This is a good answer, but since I have clarified my question somewhat, you may wish to review this answer too.

Comment: @Infinite_Maelstrom, sorry to say, but edits cannot invalidate existing answers. I understand you want your question to be open, but any edit you do has to comply with the answers you already got.

Comment: @Infinite_Maelstrom - to second what L.Dutch said - if the question has changed so radically that the existing answers are now not applicable - then best to ask a new question. Afterall - there's no charge for asking a new question :)

Comment: @L.Dutch I disagree that my edit invalidated this answer.  I simply wished to inform TheDemonLord that I had significantly adjusted the question, so that he might adjust his answer if he saw fit.  I commented on this answer specifically because some of the ideas in it influenced my edit.  I have now adjusted the edit I made to reduce its references to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at our own species, the biggest part of our domination of the planet was our ability to use tools more efficiently than other creatures.

While other species can use tools, we are by far the best users of them which has allowed us to expand throughout the world even in extreme climates such as the arctic. There's more factors to our success of course (namely that we're social with the ability to communicate ideas and teach younger members of ours species) but if we didn't have the ability to craft tools, or have a more limited version of doing so, I don't think we would've been able to spread or at least not nearly as quickly.